# Creating y shape random float array in J

Tags: j

I am trying to creating y shape random float array, and this is my current right now:

```
input_dim =: 2
hidden_dim =: 16

0 ?@$ ~ (input_dim, hidden_dim) 

0.838135  0.96131 0.766721 0.420625 0.640265 0.683779 0.683311 0.427981 0.281479 0.305607 0.385446 0.898389  0.24596 0.452391 0.739534 0.973384
0.914155 0.172582 0.146184 0.624908 0.333564 0.132774 0.475515 0.802788 0.277571 0.146896  0.40596 0.735201 0.943969 0.259493 0.442858 0.374871
```

It seems like this code returns what I exactly want, so I tried to make a function like below:

```
rand =: 0 ?@$ ~
```

but `rand (input_dim, hidden_dim)` gives me a syntax error...

I think I am missing one very important part, but I am not sure what that is.

Any advice would be grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing missing from your verb is `]`.
That is:

```
   rand =: 0 ?@$~ ]
   rand 2 3
0.891663 0.888594 0.716629
  0.9962 0.477721 0.946355
```

Potentially your confusion arose because you were wanting to create a [fork](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/fork) of the form `(noun verb verb)`, however `~` is an adverb and so combines with the verb to its left to create a new verb (in your case `?@$~`) so your `rand` had the form `(0 ?@$~)` or `(noun verb)` which J does not recognise - hence the syntax error.

It makes sense to use the combination `?@$` if possible because it is supported by [special code](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/SpecialCombinations) and does not create `x $ y`.

Answer (score 3):

Without the argument, the syntax of `0 ?@$ ~` is ambiguous and the interpreter missclassifies the parenthesization (or, more accurately, the correct parenthesization is not the one you think it is). 
The easiest way around this is to define `rand` as:

```
rand =: 3 :'0 ?@$ ~ y'
```

Of course, any other way of removing the syntactic ambiguity will also work:

```
rand =: [: ? 0 $~ ]
rand =: ?@(0$~])
rand =: ?@(0&($~))
...
```

Comment: randMonad =: ?@$&0